# Redirect Wordpress blog posts to new site, truncating title

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

So there is a lot of helpful posts here on redirecting a Wordpress blog from site A to site B, but I'm after something slightly more complicated.

I'm looking to do something like redirect:

> http://www.site1.com/2014/02/06/some-really-long-title

to:

> http://www.site2.com/blog/view/some-really-long-title-truncated

In addition, the post title is truncated to 100 characters on site2, so this adds the extra layer of complexity I don't know how to solve?

**EDIT**: 
To summarize, here is what I'm after

1: I need to remove the '/2014/02/06/' and replace with '/blog/view/'

2: I need to truncate the title, from 'some-really-long-title' to 'some-really-long-title-truncated'. Specifically, the title on the new site will be of the type varchar(100)

**EDIT 2**: 
So I have this partially working, just need to iron out how to truncate the title now??
Here's what I've got thus far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.site2.com/blog/view/$4 [R=301,NC,L]
```

So Basically $1 is now the year, $2 is the day of the month, $3 is the month, and finally $4 is the post title. Perfect! That's what I needed.

Now how would I go about shortening it to 100 characters? I essentially need {,100} but don't know how to apply that regex to the $4 variable before appending it to the redirect URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that both removes the date, and truncates the url before the redirect.

So here is what works:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/_]{0,75})(.*)$ http://www. site2.com/blog/view/$4 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Basically, I used

> ([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]{0,75})

to match the 75 characters I was after, then I had to add the

> (.*)

Because otherwise it didn't match any URLs that had a title greater than 75, so I had to take that into account.

Now the **$4** variable contains the first 75 characters of the URL, and the other variables aren't used, but 1-3 are the date, and 5 is the part that gets trimmed off.

Answer (score 0):

First upload site1 backup files and sql to site2 filemanager. go to phpmyadmin and edit database> wp-options table. first line siteurl site1.com to site2.com. go to wp-admin>options-general.php change wordpress address and site address to site2.com 
now redirect site1.com to new domain via .htaccess
edit .htaccess of site1.com and replace with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !site2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

now

```
http://www.site1.com/2014/02/06/some-really-long-title
```

redirect to:

```
http://www.site2.com/2014/02/06/some-really-long-title
```

Comment: This only solves part of problem. Please read OP. I don't need a simple redirect, there are some extra specifications. 1: I need to remove the '/2014/02/06/' and replace with '/blog/view/'. 2: I need to truncate the title, from 'some-really-long-title' to 'some-really-long-title-truncated'. Specifically, the title on the new site will be of the type varchar(100).